# Select calculated field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, compiler-errors, linq-to-entities

How Can to select the duration as difference between two field in Entity framework. Following is the corresponding SQL queries:

```
SELECT InitiateTime, StartTime, EndTime, Ano,Bno,  datediff(s,StartTime,EndTime) as duration
FROM [NEPALIVR2].[dbo].[CDR]
WHERE StartTime >= startDate and StartTime <= endDate order by StartTime desc
```

**LINQ**

```
from u in db.CDRs 
where u.InitiateTime >= startDate && u.InitiateTime <= endDate 
orderby u.InitiateTime descending 
select new
{
   InitiateTime = u.InitiateTime,
   StartTime = u.StartTime,
   EndTime = u.StartTime,
   Ano = u.Ano,
   Bno = u.Bno,
   Duration = (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("mi", u.StartTime, u.EndTime))/360,
};
```

This returns error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'` to `'System.Linq.IQueryable<IVRControlPanel.Models.CDR>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your problem not in difference calculation, but in anonymous type you are returning from query. Change it to `CDR` object:

```
select new CDR
{
   InitiateTime = u.InitiateTime,
   StartTime = u.StartTime,
   EndTime = u.StartTime,
   Ano = u.Ano,
   Bno = u.Bno,
   Duration = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("mi", u.StartTime, u.EndTime)/360
});
```

Comment: If I have create new CDR then error is `no definition of Duration in CDR`

Comment: @CodeManiac are you using CodeFirst, or mapping to existing database?

Comment: @CodeManiac well, entities are generated as partial classes. Create partial CDR class with `Duration` property. That will do the trick. Btw you can also move duration calculation to that property. Just make sure your partial CDR class defined in same namespace as CDR that was generated